# No error but no output for in automating search process in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to go to a website. Search a keyword there and get few details of HP products found in search results.This is my code, there's no error but no output either.Sometimes I get StaleElementException as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome( "C:\All\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get('https://www.insight.com/en_US/search.html')
driver.find_element_by_id("search-tab-banner-box-input").send_keys("printer")
wait( driver, 10 ).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located( (By.ID, "search-tab-banner-box-input") ) ).send_keys(Keys.ENTER )
wait( driver, 10 ).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located( (By.ID, "search-tab-banner-box-input") ) ).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE )
items_count = 0

while True:
 try:
  items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("prod-section-container")

  for index, item in enumerate( items ):
      if 'HP'in item.text:
          print(index, item.text, item.find_element_by_class_name('prod-part-number show-for-medium-up'))

  items_count += len( items )
 except:
  break

  try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath( '//div[@class="next-btn"]/a' ).click()
  except:
      break
```

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's quite possible that you are hiding the error diagnostics by using the `try ... except` constructions in your code. You should at least print out some part of whatever exception message arises and where it occurs. Although you haven't asked for advice I'm going to presume to do so. Whenever I am debugging code like this I invariably do so in an interactive programming environment so that I can examine and check results as they come in. For instance, I would look at the number of `items` and then look at one of them to see whether it was what I expected it to be.

Comment: Hi, I tried removing the try... except. I did check the no of items and there is no problem.It enters into for loop, however, it is not going into if loop I believe as it doesn't print the content inside the if loop. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `find_element_by_class_name('prod-part-number')` (rather than `find_element_by_class_name('prod-part-number show-for-medium-up')`).

```
>>> item = items[0]
>>> item
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f81b46ea9715f98e1eaf6e35ae62f601", element="0.9138180044548743-2")>
>>> item.text
'HP LaserJet Enterprise M506n - printer - monochrome - laser\nInsight Part # : F2A68A#BGJ\nMfr Part #: F2A68A#BGJ\n1 year warranty\nAdd to My Compare List\nCompare Similar\nList priceUSD $649.99\n3,710 in stock\nAdd to Cart'
>>> 
>>> item.find_element_by_class_name('prod-part-number show-for-medium-up')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 291, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 511, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

>>> item.find_element_by_class_name('prod-part-number')
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f81b46ea9715f98e1eaf6e35ae62f601", element="0.9138180044548743-12")>
>>> item.find_element_by_class_name('prod-part-number').text
'Insight Part # : F2A68A#BGJ\nMfr Part #: F2A68A#BGJ'
```

Comment: item.find_element_by_class_name('prod-part-number').text this helped